# Access to Vuex store state from a component using Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm trying to pass a list of button names into a menu component from the Vuex store following https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store

my /store/store.js:

```
export const state = () => ({
    'toolbarActions' : [ 'My project', 'Home', 'About', 'Contact' ]
})
```

My menu component:

```
<template>
  <v-toolbar color="indigo" dark>
    <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
       <v-btn flat v-for="action in toolbarActions" :key="action">{{action}}</v-btn>
             <!-- <v-btn flat v-for="action in toolbarActions">{{action}}</v-btn> -->
      <!-- <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn> -->
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>

<script>

// import toolbarActions from '~/store/store.js'

export default {
computed: {
  toolbarActions() {
          return this.$store.state.toolbarActions

          // return [ 'My project', 'Home', 'About', 'Contact' ]
  }
  }
}
</script>
```

If I uncomment:

```
      // return [ 'My project', 'Home', 'About', 'Contact' ]
```

and comment:

```
          return this.$store.state.toolbarActions
```

The button names are passed into the component. but with

```
 return this.$store.state.toolbarActions
```

not commented, nothing is passed in.

How do I access the Vuex store here to pass in the button names?

EDIT: I've made the changes, I'm getting:

```
   ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 
 'toolbarActions' of undefined"                                                                                                           
  11:52:20

  found in

 ---> <Menu> at components/menu.vue
   <Default> at layouts/default.vue
     <Root>

 » store\_toolbar.js
```

Comment: what's the issue ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim is that clearer?

Comment: yes it's clear but i recommend to share the store code as text not as screenshot

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim  I've added ir above

Comment: the file name should be `toolbar.js` not `_toolbar.js` please remove the `_`

Comment: I've made the changes. Its working! Based on this I understand the state.toolbar.toolbaractions. But where does "this.$store" come from?

Comment: read this https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#activate-the-store, nuxt will automatically inject `store`  property inside vue instance `new Vue()`

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: from those docs - > We don't need to install vuex since it's shipped with Nuxt.js.

We can now use this.$store inside our components:

<template>
  <button @click="$store.commit('increment')">{{ $store.state.counter }}</button>
</template>

Comment: you could but it's not a good practice, try to not put a lot of logic inside the template, something like `@click="'increment"` is more clean than `@click="$store.commit('increment')"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use a module named `toolbar` inside it put the following code :

```
  export const state = () => ({
     'toolbarActions' : [ 'My project', 'Home', 'About', 'Contact' ]
   })
```

the folder structure should be like :

```
.
.
> static
v store
  |_toolbar.js
```

and your `computed` property should be like :

```
computed: {
  toolbarActions() {
      return this.$store.state.toolbar.toolbarActions  //look i added the name of the toolbar module
                              // ^___________

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Better option may be

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
```

and use like

```
computed:mapGetters({
    toolbarActions:'toolbar/toolbarActions'
})
```